# C# - Provide type information to extension method

Tags: c#, system.reflection

We're currently doing some performance tuning on an application that made heavy use of annotations and extension methods, such as:

```cs
public static TClass TruncateToMaxLength<TClass>(this TClass inClass)
{
   foreach (PropertyInfo classProp in typeof(TClass).GetProperties())
   var maxLengthAttribute = classProp.GetCustomMetaDataAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
   if (null != maxLengthAttribute)
   {
     int maxLength = maxLengthAttribute.MaximumLength;
     var inClassProp = classProp.GetValue(inClass);
     if (null != inClassProp)
     {
       var strProp = inClassProp.ToString();
       classProp.SetValue(inClass, 
         strProp.Length > maxLength ? strProp.Substring(0, maxLength) : strProp);
     }
   }
}
```

to do things like automatically trim generated strings down to the `[MaxLength()]` attribute on their associated properties. In some cases we're looking at switching over to manual implementations to avoid reflection overhead, so:

```cs
public class SimplePerson : IManualMaxLength {
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public IdNumber { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public DisplayName { get; set; }

    public void ManualMaxLength() {
       if (IdNumber?.Length > 10) IdNumber = IdNumber.Substring(0, 10);
       if (DisplayName?.Length > 100) DisplayName = DisplayName.Substring(0, 100);
    }
}

public static TClass OptimizedMaxLength<TClass>(this TClass inClass)
{
   if (inClass is IManualMaxLength manualClass) manualClass.ManualMaxLength();
   else inClass.TruncateToMaxLength();
   return inClass;
}
```

where the manual operation is implemented as a class method without reflection.

In order to verify that all the manual operations match what the reflection operations would be, I had the idea to set up a test rig along the following lines, to automatically check all optimization work:

```cs
foreach (var manualType in (
    from x in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IManualMaxLength)).GetTypes()
    where x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IManualMaxLength)) 
    select x))
{
    var implManual = (IManualOperation)Activator.CreateInstance(manualType);
    var implAuto = Activator.CreateInstance(manualType);

    //some setup of properties

    implManual.ManualMaxLength();
    implAuto.TruncateToMaxLength();

    //assert rig
}
```

The rig iterates through the assembly and grabs all types that implement `IManualMaxLength`; it then uses `Activator.CreateInstance()` to set up a test case and compares the manual implementation to the expected outcome obtained by reflection.

When `implAuto` is a `SimplePerson`, I expect that to be used in `TruncateToMaxLength` to make the test rig accurate. But the call is being made for a `TClass` of `object`. That is what comes out of the call to `Activator.CreateInstance()` but it doesn't have any properties.

Now, to perform the setup and asserts I had to make a call to `manualType.GetProperties()`, and I can create an overload as follows:

```cs
public static TClass TruncateToMaxLength<TClass>
   (this TClass inClass, PropertyInfo[] testProperties = null)
{
   var propertyInfo = testProperties ?? typeof(TClass).GetProperties();
   foreach (PropertyInfo classProp in propertyinfo)
   var maxLengthAttribute = classProp.GetCustomMetaDataAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
   if (null != maxLengthAttribute)
   {
     int maxLength = maxLengthAttribute.MaximumLength;
     var inClassProp = classProp.GetValue(inClass);
     if (null != inClassProp)
     {
       var strProp = inClassProp.ToString();
       classProp.SetValue(inClass, 
         strProp.Length > maxLength ? strProp.Substring(0, maxLength) : strProp);
     }
   }
}
```

but I don't really want to do that on an extension method that's never intended to take it during normal operation.

Am I stuck doing that anyway, or is there some other way to provide the elements of a created type in a way that an extension method will pick it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `TruncateToMaxLength<TClass>`, you can use `inClass.GetType().GetProperties()` instead of `typeof(TClass).GetProperties`.

```
public static void TruncateToMaxLength<TClass>(this TClass inClass)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo classProp in inClass.GetType().GetProperties()) // This Line
    {
        var maxLengthAttribute = classProp.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
        if (null != maxLengthAttribute)
        {
            int maxLength = maxLengthAttribute.MaximumLength;
            var inClassProp = classProp.GetValue(inClass);
            if (null != inClassProp)
            {
                var strProp = inClassProp.ToString();
                classProp.SetValue(inClass,
                    strProp.Length > maxLength ? strProp.Substring(0, maxLength) : strProp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That seemed to work for me using your case of `SimplePerson`. One thing to be aware of if doing it this way would cause `TruncateToMaxLength` to execute on the properties of `inClass`'s type. So, if you had something like...

```csharp
public interface IHaveAnId
{
   [MaxLength(5)]
   string Id { get; set; }
}

public class SimplePerson : IHaveAnId
{
   [MaxLength(10)]
   public string Id { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public void Main()
{
   IHaveAnId s = new SimplePerson();
   s.TruncateToMaxLength(); 
}
```

Then the call to `s.TruncateToMaxLength` will operate on all the properties of `SimplePerson` and use the `MaxLength` attribute on that `class`' properties.

As an aside, I don't know what your performance requirements are, but you can speed up `TruncateToMaxLength<TClass>`. It'll never be as fast as your `ManualMaxLength` (at the very least I'm not clever enough to get something that fast with reflection), but you can make some gains over what you have now by caching the `PropertyInfo` instances and the `MaxLength` value.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class Extensions
{
   public static void TruncateToMaxLengthCached<TClass>(this TClass input)
   {
      var type = typeof(TClass);
      var props = _cache.GetOrAdd(type, t =>
      {
         return new Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<MaxLengthData>>(() => BuildData(input));
      }).Value;
      foreach (var data in props)
      {
         var value = data.Property.GetValue(input)?.ToString();
         if (value?.Length > data.MaxLength)
         {
            data.Property.SetValue(input, value.Substring(0, data.MaxLength));
         }
      }
   }

   private static IReadOnlyCollection<MaxLengthData> BuildData<TClass>(TClass input)
   {
      Type type = typeof(TClass);
      var result = new List<MaxLengthData>();
      foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
      {
         var maxLengthAttribute = prop.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
         if (null != maxLengthAttribute)
         {
            result.Add(new MaxLengthData
            {
               MaxLength = maxLengthAttribute.Length,
               Property = prop,
               TargetType = type
            });
         }
      }
      return result;
   }

   private static ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<MaxLengthData>>> _cache =
      new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<MaxLengthData>>>();
   private class MaxLengthData
   {
      public Type TargetType { get; set; }
      public PropertyInfo Property { get; set; }
      public int MaxLength { get; set; }
   }
}
```

And the BenchmarkDotNet results:

```
|           Method |             Id |                  Name |          Mean |       Error |      StdDev | Rank |
|----------------- |--------------- |---------------------- |--------------:|------------:|------------:|-----:|
|   ManualTruncate | 09123456789093 |          John Johnson |     28.103 ns |   0.6188 ns |   0.8046 ns |    2 |
| OriginalTruncate | 09123456789093 |          John Johnson | 17,953.005 ns | 356.7870 ns | 534.0220 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate | 09123456789093 |          John Johnson |    697.548 ns |  13.6592 ns |  13.4152 ns |    6 |
|   ManualTruncate | 09123456789093 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] |     59.177 ns |   1.2251 ns |   1.5494 ns |    4 |
| OriginalTruncate | 09123456789093 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] | 18,333.251 ns | 365.0699 ns | 461.6966 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate | 09123456789093 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] |    995.924 ns |  19.9356 ns |  23.7319 ns |    7 |
|   ManualTruncate | 09123456789093 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] |     58.787 ns |   0.4812 ns |   0.4501 ns |    4 |
| OriginalTruncate | 09123456789093 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] | 18,032.030 ns | 220.0009 ns | 195.0251 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate | 09123456789093 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] |    977.168 ns |  19.2770 ns |  27.6465 ns |    7 |
|   ManualTruncate |              1 |          John Johnson |      6.800 ns |   0.2039 ns |   0.2651 ns |    1 |
| OriginalTruncate |              1 |          John Johnson | 18,173.803 ns | 192.1153 ns | 170.3052 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate |              1 |          John Johnson |    410.136 ns |   3.8655 ns |   3.6158 ns |    5 |
|   ManualTruncate |              1 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] |     34.886 ns |   0.7203 ns |   0.6385 ns |    3 |
| OriginalTruncate |              1 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] | 18,013.630 ns | 327.2057 ns | 306.0684 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate |              1 |  Mr. J(...), Esq [98] |    684.351 ns |  12.0877 ns |  11.3069 ns |    6 |
|   ManualTruncate |              1 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] |     34.285 ns |   0.6136 ns |   0.5124 ns |    3 |
| OriginalTruncate |              1 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] | 17,926.434 ns | 184.0216 ns | 172.1340 ns |    8 |
|   CachedTruncate |              1 | Mr. J(...)hnson [111] |    685.590 ns |   9.6743 ns |   9.0493 ns |    6 |
```

Comment: I did a quick test pass to make sure type determination vs. a typed function was quick, and it was about 5% slower, but that was extremely offset by the gains from property caching. This looks like a good way to approach things going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid passing the `testProperties` overload given the current state of the application. The problem is that the extension method takes any `object`, but the practical use of the method is with a more derived type that the properties can be reflected out of. `Activator.CreateInstance()` always returns an `object` which would need to be cast to a more derived type (which is unknown when iterating over all types that have these attributes).

You must find a way to expose the type to cast to for each concrete instance, which is going to be a lot of manual, fairly throwaway work.

Your `testProperties` overload is the best fix in my opinion. Given that the extension method will be going away in the long run once everything is converted to the more efficient manual checks, I wouldn't sweat it existing for now.

Comment: I've made a more concrete case of things in the question so I can talk about things a little more specifically. Basically, we're converting a bunch of types over to IManualMaxLength - this test rig will automatically scoop up new types as the conversion is made. TClass is a type argument in the extension method; "casting implAuto to TClass" doesn't make sense to me because the test rig is iterating over many types. Are you saying I can make a generic method in the test rig?

Comment: @Glazius ahh, I read it wrong. You have to know about the intended actual type at some point. Updating answer.

Comment: It probably is best not to worry about this, but this is a large application with lots of extensions, and "in the long run" tracking down every consumer of every TruncateToMaxLength type of function isn't going to be time-effective in addressing user concerns. I don't think that would change anything about your answer, but I wanted to say it just the same.